# Framework7 offline app cross origin blocked on IE & Chrome. Is there a simple local server solution as an alternative?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, html-framework-7, localserver, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am currently building an app using the Wordpress API and Framework7 that is solely intended for offline use. The offline app works perfectly in safari with local file restrictions disabled, however I understand a similar option is not available in IE or Chrome.

Unfortunately for me, the project is being developed exclusively for surface pro, so it has to work in IE.

This being the case, are there any alternative solutions in which I can quickly and smoothly serve the local files as a local server? Ideally avoiding the use of the command line and/or MAMP/XAMPP.

Found that tinyweb offered a solution that was almost perfect, however the local files were all 403 forbidden when loaded up.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: What about build an browser app - cordova platform add  browser- ? or run app using http-serve? ....mm..or what about define a cross local domain to webiste ..

Comment: The app is updatable from the CMS, and will download an offline version of the relevant files. It means when it goes to the client, it will not be a finished, packaged version and would require setup every time with these solutions. Looking for something I could possibly include in the directory when downloaded that could be updated with PHP to open the app on a click (like tinyweb but without all the filepath errors)

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate to encase your app in a [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org) app for Windows.

Or, if it suits your needs, a quick and dirty solution is [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg).